# How do I solve this 403 error in Wordpress?

Tags: html, wordpress, content-management-system

[image]

Please help as I am unable to post media on wordpress cms.

Comment: provide .htaccess file

Answer (score 0):

Often the 403 error is caused by a corrupt .htaccess file in your WordPress site. Repairing this file is quite easy.
First you need to connect to your website using a FTP client.

You need to download the .htaccess file to your computer so that you have a fresh backup of it. After that, you need to delete the file from your server.

Try accessing your website. If 403 forbidden error is resolved, then this means that your .htaccess file was corrupt.
You can generate a fresh .htaccess file by logging into your WordPress admin area and going to Settings » Permalinks page.

[image: generate a fresh .htaccess]

If the above does not help. then set the file permissions for the wp-admin directory (and underlying folders) to 755.

You can do this via your ftp client. Right click on the wp admin folder and then go to permissions.
[image: check file permissions]

[image: change file permissions]